# NEED to get via SQL - 1 month from today, show the day with most (user) authorizations

Tags: sql, sql-server

no problem with 1st part, have a problem with 2nd part

/*--to show last 30 days from yesterday-=*/

```
SELECT *
FROM T_USER_AUDIT 
WHERE authorization_time >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())
and authorization_time <= getdate()
```

/*--to show the day with most authorization--*/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for aggregation and `order by`?

```
SELECT TOP (1) CONVERT(DATE, authorization_time), COUNT(*)
FROM T_USER_AUDIT 
WHERE authorization_time >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) AND
      authorization_time <= getdate() 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, authorization_time)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

You say the current code works, but I am suspicious.  `GETDATE()` returns a time component, which affects the comparison.  This means that you have partial days for the first and last day.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust this for your database (assumed SQLServer)

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(authorization_time as DATE) topdate
FROM T_USER_AUDIT 
WHERE authorization_time >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())
and authorization_time <= getdate() 
GROUP BY CAST(authorization_time as DATE)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you...
And how do I run this command via slqcmd
Some thing like: sqlcmd -u ** -h localhost -p ******* DATABASE and location of .sql file with current query?

Comment: If it's sql server I'd use SSMS, if MySQL I like Heidi.. if it's command line then sure. I tried d to write sql in SSMS then use them in a c# app